# pick up number and name from contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app i have two EditText and one Button. If i press button i want to pick contact name and number in those two editbox.

```
    <EditText android:textSize="16.0dip" 
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:id="@+id/contact_numbersub" 
        android:layout_width="160.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="36.0dip" 
        android:text="Mobile" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_number" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/contact_number"
        android:textSize="16.0dip" 
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_width="160.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="36.0dip" 
        android:text="Unknown Caller" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

              <Button 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:id="@+id/contactbutton" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/contactlist" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contact_label" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/contactimage" 
        android:onClick="onClickSelectContact"/>
```

And I have defined onActivityResult method for pickup image from gallery. So I got difficulty here to retrieve contact name and number. Image retrieves successfully but i have no solution for contacts retrieval

Grateful to anyone that can help.

Comment: Your question is some how confusing. you mean text from the edittext views or contact name and number from contacts app?

Comment: You mean, you have two `startActivityFor Result()`, so need separate actions for the two inside `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: i mean i want to retrieve name and number from contact list and set them into edittext field

Comment: Nizam .. no there is onActivityResult() only one method and i used it to pickup image from gallery , now i want to pickup contact but I got all suggestion through that method , but no success for both image and contact pickup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not complete solution, but I hope it'll be some what useful.

Suppose my button clicks are as below

```
   btncontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,1);//Request_code is 1
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i,2);//Request_code is 2
    }
});
```

Now, for onActivityResult,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(data!=null && data.getData()!=null){
        Uri _uri=data.getData();
            Log.d("Nzm", ""+_uri);


        switch(requestCode){
                    case 1:
                           // you have _uri in your hand which have contact id. Do necessary steps for contact as you want here.
                          break;
                    case 2:// Action for your image
                           Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                           i.setData(_uri);
                           startActivity(i);
                           break;
                    }
              }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Accessing Contacts Data](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html)?  Pay particular attention to *Retrieving Details for a Contact*.

Comment: yes i saw it, and I also follow it. I fill required permissions and all stuff, but due to image pickup onActivityResult is being overriding so got error....